# google's recaptcha 2 validation - how to do it

Tags: node.js, api, validation, express, recaptcha

Ive got problems with google recaptcha verification. Thats what I have in my form register.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mySiteKey" data-callback='validate'>
</div>
```

I know that I have to verify on both sides. On client side I need to know if the recaptcha was fulfilled (data-callback function)? So if theres a response from google server's right? Then on serverside I need to send a request to google api with siteKey and response? Then if the result is success validation is ok otherwise not?

Comment: you might want to check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcGIA7d5cA0

Comment: ok, i did something like this: http://prntscr.com/gag0rt, but it doesnt work that well. It doesnt render registered view if susscess: true (google api response). I mean. After registered I want to say something like: You have successfuly... And I dont know where exactly should I reset google widget/

Comment: I think what you asking is a redirect page for confirmation on register

Comment: Yeah, but it doesnt work. Look. This is google response: http://prntscr.com/gag5wv. Heres the code:
        `if(data.success !== undefined && !data.success) {
            return res.json({
                "responseCode": 1,
                "responseDesc": 'Failed captcha verification'
            });
            res.redirect('/');
        };`

Comment: Ok.. I had res.redirect in a wrong place..